# SignalR like functionality is not working

Tags: asp.net, angular, signalr, signalr-hub

I have created a like functionality so that a user can like a post in my app. I've read about SignalR and I tried using it so that the number of likes can be automatically updated in real-time whenever a user likes/unlikes a post. However, it does not work, but I also receive no errors. The only message in my console after pressing the like button is:

```
Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44351/hubs/like?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIxIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJnZW9yZ2lhIiwicm9sZSI6WyJNZW1iZXIiLCJBZG1pbiJdLCJuYmYiOjE2MTk0NjQ3NzAsImV4cCI6MTYyMDA2OTU3MCwiaWF0IjoxNjE5NDY0NzcwfQ.1Bwf_Y2QJP_VjRUXaBeqz5sueV6oTIpVlOLU4kOEmLf2Y_hfxJbc5_f4yksY9R45YGz0qPWw-rc10I7pobFJYQ
```

This is my .net code:

```
 public class LikeHub : Hub
  {
        private readonly IPostRepository _postRepository;
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public LikeHub(IPostRepository postRepository, DataContext context, IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _postRepository = postRepository;
            _context = context;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        public async Task SetLike(int userId, int postId)
        {
            Like l = new Like();

            Like temp = _context.Likes.Where(x => x.PostId == postId && x.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();

            if(temp != null)
            {
                _context.Likes.Remove(temp);
            } else
            {
                _context.Likes.Add(l);

                l.UserId = userId;
                l.PostId = postId;
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            int numOfLikes = _context.Likes.Where(x => x.PostId == postId).Count();

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", numOfLikes, postId, userId);

        }
   }
```

And this is my Angular code in the PostsService:

```
export class PostsService {

  hubUrl = environment.hubUrl;
  private hubConnection: HubConnection;
  likeMessageReceive: EventEmitter<{ numOfLikes: number, postId: number, userId: number }> = new EventEmitter<{ numOfLikes:number, postId: number, userId: number }>();


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   connectHubs(user: User) { 
      this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.hubUrl + 'like', { accessTokenFactory: () => user.token, 
      skipNegotiation: true, transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets })
      .build();
  
      return  this.hubConnection.start()
                 .then(() => {
                     this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (numOfLikes, postId, userId) => {
                       this.likeMessageReceive.emit({ numOfLikes, postId, userId });
                     });
                 })
                 .catch(error => console.log(error)); 
  }
  
  setLike(userId: number, postId: number) {
       this.hubConnection.invoke('SetLike', userId, postId);
  }
  
  closeHubConnections() {
      this.hubConnection.stop();
  }
}
```

This is the Angular code in my PostCardComponent, where the like button is:

```
export class PostCardComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input() post: Post;
  likesSubscription: Subscription;

 
  constructor(private postService:PostsService,public accountService:AccountService)
            { this.Login$ = this.accountService.Logged;}
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.likesSubscription = this.postService.likeMessageReceive.subscribe(result =>{
      if (result.postId === this.post.id) {
          this.post.likes.length = result.numOfLikes;
      }
  })
}

liked(post: Post) {
    const user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    this.postService.setLike(user.id, post.id);
  }
}
```

This is the PostListComponent, where all the posts are:

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: Post[];
  post: Post;
  likesSubscription: Subscription;
  localUser: User;


  constructor(private postService: PostsService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
     this.postService.connectHubs(this.localUser);
  }

}
```

I don't know if the code in `this.hubConnection.on()` is correct, or if the given parameters are correct. I have also added the LikeHub in my endpoints in the Startup.cs class.

Comment: Can you please add console.log(numOfLikes) in the on handler and see what are you receiving?
What do you mean it doesn't work? Is database updated? Also why do you update user id with the id of liked user?

Comment: Database is not updated. The userId is the id of the user who liked the post and postId is the id of the liked post. No data is displayed if I write console.log(numOfLikes), the breakpoint doesn't even reach that point. It's maybe because I've used then()?

Comment: Oh, really, didn't even notice :D 
Try to move this .on listener up, after you make HubConnectionBuilder().**.build()

Comment: The user and the post parameter passed to the createLike() method are sent correctly. I've updated the code and I separated connectionHub.on() from connectionHub.start(). Now the breakpoint reaches connectionHub.on(), but it still doesn't reach the conole.log(numOfLikes)

Comment: I've moved .on after the build, but still the same result. Do I maybe need to use Clients.Caller.SendAsync() in my backend?

Comment: No, i don't thin so, this way you will only send it to your calling client

Comment: okay, the other thing i have just notice is that you create a new connection every time you like, i think you need to create connection only once you open application

Comment: oh, and you don't even invoke server side hub

Comment: Oh ok, but what is the correct way to do that? I am new to SignalR and I'm still struggling to understand all its concepts.

Comment: I have added a new line of code to invoke the server side method and I'm getting this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.

Comment: Probably i should make it as answer to have opportunity to make code examples, but in a word, you probably can make some ConnectHubs() method in your service and call it on init of some of your base controllers. There you will have all the code related to hubConnection.start(). And instead of this all code in that service method you will only need some invocation

Comment: yeah, thats because you need to wait for connection to start and only then invoke messages. I will better make an answer with some code examples and links

Comment: That would be really great!

Comment: Sorry, this is asp.net core, right?

Comment: Yes. And if it is of interest, my Like class from the database contains the id of the liked post, the id of the user who liked a post and the date when the like was created.

Comment: Sorry, you were right about placing .on method in the beginning, thats how it is in some angular examples, it should have worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend to start from carefully rewriting this example, this should really help to understand concepts better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

So, there are couple of problems in this code. createLike method of PostsService should be only responsible to post invocation via existing connection. All other code responsible for connection start should be already executed until this moment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#connect-to-a-hub

So, if you are not familiar with reactive programming and rxjs, i would recommend you to add some method to your PostsService like ConnectHubs(): Promise to prepare your hub connections, before actually invoke some hub methods.

```
connectHubs() { 
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(this.hubUrl + 'like', { accessTokenFactory: () => user.token, 
    skipNegotiation: true, transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets })
    .build();

    return  this.hubConnection.start()
               .then(() => {
                   this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (numOfLikes, postId, userId) => {
                       // some logic to handle invocation
                   });
               })
               .catch(error => console.log(error)); 
}

setLike(userId: number, postId: number) {
     this.hubConnection.invoke('SetLike', userId, postId);
}

closeHubConnections() {
    this.hubConnection.stop();
}
```

And then in component that holds multiple posts, apart of requesting all posts from api, you will need to also invoke this connectHubs method and wait for this promise to show all the posts, to avoid likes being set before it is possible. In this case it will be better to also stop connection in ngOnDestroy to avoid unnecessary multiple active connections to the same hub from one client. Or you can just call this init method in you very base component, like app component, in this case you will not need to stop connection in ngOnDestroy, but you will need to make sure your user is logged in before connection established. Maybe you can find some component where it would be a rare case for it to be destroyed, but it will always be opened after login

If you know rxjs you can add some BehaviorSubject field like

```
private isConnectedSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);
isConnected$ = isConnectedSubject.asObservable();
```

and then instead of returning a promise on connection start, you can just add something like isConnectedSubject.next(true);
and in your disconnection method you can add isConnectedSubject.next(false);
In your component you can just disable like button while hub isn't connected this way:

```
<button [disabled]="!(postService.isConnected$ | async)" ...>
```

To make your controls aware of changes in this hub, if you know RxJS, you can add some Subject field with its Observable field and post events every time new message is received. Or you can make it easier way with event emitter https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter , like below

service:

```
likeMessageReceive = new EventEmitter<{ numOfLikes, postId, userId }>();

connectHubs() {
   ....
   this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (numOfLikes, postId, userId) => {
     likeMessageReceive.emit({ numOfLikes, postId, userId })
     console.log(numOfLikes);
   })
   ....
```

Post component:

```
likesSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.likesSubscription = this.postsService.likeMessageReceive.subscribe(result =>{
        if (result.postId === this.post.id) {
            this.post.likes.length = numOfLikes;
        }
    })
}

liked(post: Post) {
    const user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    this.postService.setLike(user.id, post.id);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.likesSubscription) {
        this.likesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

With rxjs it would be pretty same, but you will use Subject instead of emitter, don't forget about unsubscribing to avoid unexpected behavior and leaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will carefully read this and I will try to update my code after these examples so that it fits my needs.

Comment: Ok so I have tried to implement your suggestions and I updated the Angular code in my question with what I have received. Something is clearly wrong since my posts are not loading anymore and I get this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` in the OnInit from PostListComponent. The like button will not even apeear if the user is not logged in, so I don't need to disable it. I think maybe the code in the OnInit of PostList is not quite right, but does the rest seem ok?

Comment: @Alessia okay, first, you didn't instantiate the event emitter, probably i forgot to add this code, you needed to create it first to use it like this: likeMessageReceive = new EventEmitter<{ numOfLikes, postId, userId }>();

Comment: @Alessia and you are still creating hub conenction instead of making method invocation. You needed to add connectHubs() in soe ngOnInit, for example of list, and then just make invocations in your liked method, will update the answer, the code that you are placing in on was supposed to be inside of subscribe

Comment: But how can I access numOfLikes in OnInit of the postList? I thought through the fact that numOfLikes is emitted by the event emitter, but it seems unknown. I have edited the code

Comment: Or should the code I've placed in the PostListComponent actually be in the PostCardComponent? Since this is the place where the like button is.

Comment: @Alessia i suppose that this connectHubs method shouldn't catually be aware of some specific post and user, post and user should be taken care of in event emitter listener which is in PostCardComponent, what do you think?

Comment: @Alessia hm, strange it is unknown, is the value correct in the signalR .on handler? Or do you mean compilation errors?

Comment: Ok, the post is useless, but I need the user so that I can access user.token. And I meant that numOfLikes is unknown in the code, I can't compile it. It says `cannot find name 'numOfLikes'`

Comment: understood, if it is in localStorage, you can probably get its value from there. Oh, i'v got it about numberofLikes, it should have been result.numOfLikes. Sorry, didn't test this code on my local before adding

Comment: Yes right that was kinda obvious I don't know how I've missed that

Comment: Now I get this error in the console `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined`

Comment: Ok so this.post.likes.length in OnInit contains the correct value, but console.log(result.numOfLikes) doesn't show anything

Comment: @Alessia Okay, thats strange it is undefined, do you provide this service only in module? and are you sure connectHubs is executed before liked method?
Thats also strange that this isn't logged

Comment: Yes, I'm providing the service in the PostCardComponent in the constructor of the component. But I'm not sure if connectHubs is executed before liked method and I'm not actually referencing connectHubs() method anywhere. The code I've posted is the code at this moment.

Comment: So when you are calling connectHubs in list component, do you make some Promise.all() to wait for both xhr to retrieve components and for this method?
By provide I meant do you register this service in provide: [...] property of module, or in same field of component? Or you don't register it at all?

Comment: The only thing I'm doing is that I am calling this.postService.connectHubs(this.localUser) in the OnInit method of PostListComponent(I have also written this code in my question) and after pressing a like button I get this: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Failed to invoke 'SetLike' due to an error on the server.
Error: Failed to invoke 'SetLike' due to an error on the server.` But I don't see a proble with my backend method.

Comment: @Alessia Okay, at least the error is different now, some server error

Comment: @Alessia any stack traces in output window of your visual studio or probably some exceptions? Is server code of your hub method accessible by breakpoint?

Comment: Nope, you're right, it's not even accessible

Comment: @Alessia oh, okay, could you find this websocket connection in network tab and show what messages are sent through it? To do that i think you need to open this page, then open network tab, then refresh the page, set some like and find some WS connection. You will have Messages option there

Comment: The only message I'm receiving from that websocket connection is `{"type":6}` This is the request Url: `wss://localhost:44351/hubs/like?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiI1IiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJtYWRhbGluYSIsInJvbGUiOiJNZW1iZXIiLCJuYmYiOjE2MTk4OTcyODgsImV4cCI6MTYyMDUwMjA4OCwiaWF0IjoxNjE5ODk3Mjg4fQ.L2JlQW1pZoOwFITkKuoce_TevbcS4yskzz1CRysvevaz8D7-zduci-PeFSISyQPorUTIJ9r5CsSeeJAwdcUuiA` why does it start with wws instead of https?

Comment: @Alessia even after setting some likes?

Comment: What do you mean by setting likes? Pressing the like button? Then yes, even after that

Comment: @Alessia well, i think because the transport is WebSockets, with http requests it would be unable to post some messges from server to clients without waiting for Poll requests from them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API  Here it says two-way connection, which means you can send messages both from client to server and from server to client through a connection any time

Comment: @Alessia oh okay, try to make some @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class PostService .... It will make this service singleton on the frontend

Comment: @Alessia maybe it is provided every time new

Comment: Do I maybe need a tracker on the backend? I've seen that on other examples with signalr

Comment: I've tried adding the @Injectable, but same error

Comment: not sure what you are talking about exactly, didn't heard about trackers. Can you send a link? and do you make MapHub on the backend?

Comment: @Alessia thats strange it doesn't send any invocation messages on setLike from the client

Comment: this is the link https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/tracking-online-users-with-signalr/. And yes, I'm mapping the hub like this in the startup class: `endpoints.MapHub<LikeHub>("hubs/like");`

Comment: @Alessia no, i don't think that tracking is necessary

Comment: @Alessia you sure you have All filter set in websockets messages? Or maybe you have Receive set

Comment: Yes. I’ve also tried switching all and receive and it’s the same answer.

Comment: @Alessia hm, can you try to add some OnConnectedAsync to your hub and see if it gets called when connection is established

Comment: Yes, but I have to leave now and I will be back in an hour. Should I add something in OnConnectedAsync() ?

Comment: @Alessia I don't think so, sorry, i'll leave now too, don't know how to better handle this issue, i'll be back tomorrow

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for helping me out with this

Comment: Ok so I have added  public override async Task OnConnectedAsync() in my LikeHub and yes, it gets called, the breakpoint set there is reached. Should I somehow move my code in there?

Comment: no, i think we should better understand why we can't call this invoke

Comment: Hmm ok yes. I thought we had to use OnConnectedAsync()

Comment: @Alessia any stack traces with this error?

Comment: @Alessia are you sure no messages sent through websocket? It looks like only server can generate this message

Comment: @Alessia maybe i am missing something, what is your asp.net core version?

Comment: Asp .Net Core version 3.1. Well, in my network tab in the response of that request there was only that message. Is there some input I can give so that the mesaage changes?

Comment: @Alessia So, your client actually sent something?

Comment: @Alessia if it did, can you please show how invocation looked like

Comment: You mean the message from the network tab? The last version of the code is updated in the question.

Comment: I mean the message was `{"type":6}` and I'm guessing 6 because that's the number of posts per page

Comment: @Alessia no, it is keep alive message, i think we need something with types 1 and 3

Comment: @Alessia okay, maybe try to turn on negotiation again, probably it will somehow help

Comment: This is what I get when hovering over this.hubConnection() `baseUrl: (...)
cachedPingMessage: "{\"type\":6}\u001e"
callbacks: {}
closedCallbacks: []
connection: HttpConnection {features: {…}, negotiateVersion: 1, logger: ConsoleLogger, baseUrl: "https://localhost:44326/hubs/like", httpClient: DefaultHttpClient, …}
connectionId: (...)
connectionStarted: false
connectionState: "Connecting"
handshakeProtocol: HandshakeProtocol {}
invocationId: 0
logger: NullLogger {}
methods: {}
protocol: JsonHubProtocol {name: "json", version: 1, transferFormat: 1}
receivedHandshakeResponse: false`

Comment: I have turned negotiation on and in the network tab I'm getting `https://localhost:44326/hubs/like/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1`, status code 200 Ok and as a response `{"negotiateVersion":1,"connectionId":"XqKuSzY-BQ1iJuNWDPVtFA","connectionToken":"mPuphTx66hGCoYjmSM7pjQ","availableTransports":[{"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]},{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}`

Comment: @Alessia thats negotiation request, and did anything change in the ws connection?

Comment: Ah, connectioStarted: false. Is it when Invoke happens?

Comment: No, it’s in the connectionHub.on().

Comment: @Alessia So, handler in .on gets invoked after you send setLike invokation?

Comment: The message changed in the network tab. Now it's only `{}`. The breakpoint from setLike is not reached

Comment: But if I set a breakpoint in my postCardComponent where the setLike() method is called, the parameters are set correctly. Actuallt, setLike() is reached, my bad.

Comment: @Alessia and no ping messages? very strange, i don't knw, maybe you can give me a screenshot of how it looks in the network tab? More then 50 comments already :)

Comment: @Alessia oh, and is it reached on the backend? If yes then no need in screenshot

Comment: No, not on the backend. It reached the method in the postService in the frontend. In the backend is still not reaching it. What screenshot should I provide?

Comment: @Alessia screenshot of messages sent via WS connection

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15mMiLf-u0xBVBv_rjUY9Hua25g7p0_Yd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X_twmFNXqakyhrw5yBFh0r96WK23iN6V/view?usp=sharing this is for negotiation

Comment: @Alessia oh, so actually client is sending something to the server and server is responding, you see, third message is "type": 1. Will look closer and get back to you later

Comment: @Alessia i'v got it, if you look closer to arguments (field "arguments" in json object in third invocation), you will see that first argument is string '1' and it can't be binded to integer. The second argument is fine, it is number because it doesn't have quotes, it is just 25. You should check if you put a correct object into the localStorage for the user, if its id is actually a string. Quick way to check if this is the cause of the issue is to put + before userId (+userId) in setLike method of your PostsService in the invocation call

Comment: *third message, not invokation

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I put a parseInt(id) in the method call and now it works. Thank you so so much!

Comment: @Alessia you are welcome, glad i could help, it was interesting issue! :) I would still suggest you to probably change declarations of User model or method, or to ensure that id of user stored in local storage is really a number

Comment: @Alessia also, if you are not sure you fully understand all of the concepts of signalr, you can ask questions here or i can try to describe those in a word in a comments. I can see there are a lot of connections being opened, is it expected?

Comment: Well, I got the id actually by decoding the token you get when you log in and I guess this is why it was not a number. And about the connections, I am setting the connection to the hub in the OnInit in the post list and there are 6 posts per page, maybe that's why there are so many connections? Because there are exactly 6 connections that are being made.

Comment: @Alessia i think it shouldn't, hm, is list created in ngFor loop too?

Comment: Yes, I mean the method for loading the posts is also called in OnInit

Comment: And yes, in the html I am gathering the posts with a ngFor

Comment: @Alessia Okay, will try to think about it tomorrow, do you understand now that connection should be created before communication starts, because client and server methods should be invoked through it? And that thing how invocations are also sent with these messages with specific type, argument and method name fields?

Comment: Yes, I really understood the concepts better now.

Comment: Oh I solved the problem, I wasn't actually calling connectHub in the postList, I was calling it on the postCard, that's why there were 6 connections